# adding ggtitle via do.call when argument is a language object

Tags: r, ggplot2, do.call

### Consider a simple function, which adds a ggtitle to a grob

```
f <- function(PLOT, TITLE) {
  PLOT + ggtitle(TITLE)
}
```

Calling the function directly works as expected.
However, calling the function via `do.call(f, ..)` throws an error when `TITLE` is a `language` object

```
## Sample Data
TIT <- bquote(atop("This is some text",  atop(italic("Here is some more text"))))
P   <- qplot(x=1:10, y=1:10, geom="point")

## WORKS FINE
f(P, TIT)

## FAILS
do.call(f, list(P, TIT))
## Error in labs(title = label) : could not find function "atop"
```

This of course only happens when `TIT` is a language object

```
TIT.char <- "This is some text\nHere is some more text"
do.call(f, list(P, TIT.char))
## No Error
```

How can `do.call()` be used correctly when arguments are language objects?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use

```
do.call(f, list(P, TIT), quote=TRUE)
```

instead. The problem is that your expression is being evaluated when you run do.call. By setting `quote=TRUE` it will quote the arguments to leave them un-evaluated when passing them along to `f`. You can also explicitly quote `TIT`

```
do.call(f, list(P, quote(TIT)))
```

Comment: That did it think you.   I can't quote the argument directly, as I am collecting several of them programatically.  But using the `quote` param works